# D3JS V4 Stop append of a tspan based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a bit of D3.js code that creates a treemap, however I am trying to alter the code a little to stop unnecessary labels being printed for elements with a value of 0.

The following code seems to add the tspan and give it a text value. However if the value d.data.size which seems inaccessible from inside the `.text(function(d){});` is 0 I don't want a label to be shown!

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
Data structure is like:

```
{"name":"Gradings","children":[{"name":"Full Assurance","children":[{"name":"Domains","children":[{"name":"D1","size":8},{"name":"D2","size":7},{"name":"D3","size":11},{"name":"D4","size":8},{"name":"D5","size":2},{"name":"D6","size":3},{"name":"D7","size":3},{"name":"D8","size":4}]}]},{"name":"Substantial Assurance","children":[{"name":"Domains","children":[{"name":"D1","size":7},{"name":"D2","size":3},{"name":"D3","size":5},{"name":"D4","size":2},{"name":"D5","size":2},{"name":"D6","size":2},{"name":"D7","size":1},{"name":"D8","size":4}]}]},{"name":"No Assurance","children":[{"name":"Domains","children":[{"name":"D1","size":5},{"name":"D2","size":1},{"name":"D3","size":3},{"name":"D4","size":2},{"name":"D5","size":0},{"name":"D6","size":1},{"name":"D7","size":1},{"name":"D8","size":2}]}]},{"name":"Limited Assurance","children":[{"name":"Domains","children":[{"name":"D1","size":4},{"name":"D2","size":1},{"name":"D3","size":2},{"name":"D4","size":1},{"name":"D5","size":0},{"name":"D6","size":0},{"name":"D7","size":1},{"name":"D8","size":1}]}]}]}
```

Code I believe needs changing is:

```
cell.append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", function (d)
        {
            return "url(#clip-" + d.data.id + ")";
        })
        .selectAll("tspan")
        .data(function (d)
        {
            return d.data.name.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g);
        })
        .enter().append("tspan")
        .style('fill', 'black')
        .style('font-weight', 'bold')
        .attr("x", 4)
        .attr("y", function (d, i)
        {
            return 13 + i * 10;
        })
        .text(function (d)
        {
            return d;
        });
```

Comment: Please show your data structure (just a few rows/objects).

Comment: see my edit please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your enter selection, you can get the data of the parent selection with:

```
d3.select(this.parentNode).data();
```

Thus, in your `text` function, you can write something like this:

```
.text(function(d) {
    if (d3.select(this.parentNode).data()[0].size !== 0) {
        return d;
    }
})
```

Or the same thing using a ternary operator.

Here is a demo, using (part of) your data. I changed the data to make `D4` size = 0. All names will be printed, except for `D4`.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "D1",
  "size": 8
}, {
  "name": "D2",
  "size": 7
}, {
  "name": "D3",
  "size": 11
}, {
  "name": "D4",
  "size": 0
}, {
  "name": "D5",
  "size": 2
}, {
  "name": "D6",
  "size": 3
}, {
  "name": "D7",
  "size": 3
}, {
  "name": "D8",
  "size": 4
}];

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var texts = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 20 + 16 * i
  })
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.name
  })
  .enter()
  .append("tspan")
  .text(function(d) {
    if (d3.select(this.parentNode).data()[0].size !== 0) {
      return d;
    } 
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Perfect. I didn't know you could access the parent like that!